# How can I dismiss a frozen "Deleting Trash" dialog box?

Tags: macos, performance

I have the trash dialog box up, and it's frozen. What process needs to be killed in order to remove it, without having to restart?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `killall Finder` in Terminal.app.

Comment: wont that close all open programs in finder?

Comment: it will only stop the finder, no other apps. since the finder is what is frozen, it would be what you have to kill

Answer (score 6):

Relaunch the Finder if you don't want to use the terminal.
Apple menu > Force quit... > Finder > Relaunch.

Comment: This worked, easier to use than terminal for most users.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop ONLY the Empty Trash process, open the **Activity Monitor** utility and **force quit the Locum process**.

Enter your admin password when requested.

Comment: I don't see Locum. Has is been renamed?